# xamarin.forms: Images just dont seem to scale up to their container

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

Someone please help me out here!!

This image is inside a stacklayout, which is inside a scrollview. Thats basically it.
Watch this:

```
<Image BackgroundColor="Green" x:Name="img_mainPic"/>
```

[image]

Great, my picture is shown in its original size I guess, but left and right there a big green bars - empty space.

Lets add:

```
VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
```

We get:

[image]

Wtf is it doing?? Why are the green bars now at the bottom??

Ok, lets try to add:

Aspect="AspectFill"

[image]

Great, thats just so much better. Excatly what I wanted.

Ok but now for realsis:
How hard can it be to scale my image without giving it a fixed height? (because then it would work, but other pictures in others formats wont anymore...)

FULLCODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    BackgroundColor="White"
    xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:Khaled.Helpers"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:abstractions="clr-namespace:Plugin.CrossPlatformTintedImage.Abstractions;assembly=Plugin.CrossPlatformTintedImage.Abstractions"
    x:Class="Khaled.Views.Page_FullAd">
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
            <Grid>
            </Grid>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <RefreshView IsRefreshing="False" x:Name="refreshview_view" Refreshing="RefreshView_Refreshing">
           <ScrollView>
                <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                    <Image Aspect="AspectFill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="img_mainPic"/>
                    <BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource LightGray}"/>
                    <Grid HeightRequest="50">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Frame x:Name="frame_telephone" Padding="10" HasShadow="False">
                            <Image Source="btn_telephone" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Tapped_Quicks"/>
                            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Frame>
                        <Frame x:Name="frame_gps" Grid.Column="1" Padding="10"  HasShadow="False">
                            <Image Source="btn_gps" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Tapped_Quicks"/>
                            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Frame>
                        <Frame x:Name="frame_mail" Margin="2" Grid.Column="2" Padding="10"  HasShadow="False">
                            <Image Source="btn_mail" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Tapped_Quicks"/>
                            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Frame>
                        <Frame x:Name="frame_share" Grid.Column="3" Padding="10"  HasShadow="False">
                            <Image Source="btn_share" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Tapped_Quicks"/>
                            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Frame>
                        <Frame  CornerRadius="0" x:Name="frame_heart" Grid.Column="4" Padding="10"  HasShadow="False">
                            <abstractions:TintedImage TintColor="Transparent"
                                                      VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                      HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                      Source="img_fav"
                                                      x:Name="img_heart"/>
                            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Tapped_Quicks"/>
                            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Frame>
                    </Grid>
                    <BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource LightGray}"/>
                    <Grid ColumnSpacing="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Frame CornerRadius="0" Padding="5,10,5,5" x:Name="tab1" HasShadow="False" BackgroundColor="White">
                            <Label FontSize="13"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   TextColor="{StaticResource TextBlack}"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   Text="{helpers:Translate DESCRIPTION}"/>
                            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Tapped_tabs"/>
                            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Frame>
                         <Frame CornerRadius="0" Padding="5" x:Name="tab2" HasShadow="False"  BackgroundColor="{StaticResource TabGray}" Grid.Column="1">
                            <Label FontSize="13"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   TextColor="{StaticResource TextBlack}"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   Text="{helpers:Translate ACTIONS}"/>
                             <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Tapped_tabs"/>
                            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Frame>
                         <Frame CornerRadius="0" Padding="5" x:Name="tab3" HasShadow="False"  BackgroundColor="{StaticResource TabGray}"  Grid.Column="2" >
                            <Label FontSize="13"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   TextColor="{StaticResource TextBlack}"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   Text="{helpers:Translate BOOKSLOT}"/>
                             <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Tapped_tabs"/>
                            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Frame>
                    </Grid>
                    <!--changeable layouts-->
                    <StackLayout Margin="0,10,0,0" BackgroundColor="White" Padding="15" x:Name="layout1">
                        <Label TextColor="{StaticResource TextBlack}" x:Name="label_description"/>
                        <Grid Margin="0,30,0,0" RowSpacing="15" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label x:Name="label_adresse"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   FontSize="14"
                                   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Tapped_Quicks"/>
                                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Label>
                            <Label x:Name="label_hours"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   FontSize="14"
                                   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
                            <Label x:Name="label_telephone"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   FontSize="14"
                                   Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
                                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Tapped_Quicks"/>
                                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Label>
                            <Label x:Name="label_email"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   FontSize="14"
                                   Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
                                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Tapped_Quicks"/>
                                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Label>
                            <Label x:Name="label_web"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   FontSize="14"
                                   Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1">
                                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Tapped_Quicks"/>
                                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Label>
                            <Image Source="btn_gps"
                                   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <Image Source="btn_clock"
                                   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <Image Source="btn_telephone"
                                   Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <Image Source="btn_mail"
                                   Margin="3"
                                   Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <Image Source="btn_web"
                                   Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </RefreshView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Can I see your full code? like the container for this image and so on?

Comment: @FreakyAli ofc you can. I hope that will shed some light into that!

Comment: So basically what you want is your image should adjust based on its size, whatever its original size is?

Comment: HorizontalOptions=Fill?

Comment: this just stretches the images

Comment: You want the image to scale itself based on the available space, e.g. with the full width and a height relative to that, right? You could try using my AspectView to wrap the image, then set the `HorizontalOptions="Fill"` and the `VerticalOptions="Start"` on the AspectView and set the `AspectRatio` to a fixed value: https://github.com/ewerspej/epj.AspectView.Forms